# OutOfMemoryError caused by RemoteController?

Tags: java, android, service, out-of-memory

Good evening,

I've been getting many reports (but apparently only from a small subset of users) about an OOM error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2359308 byte
>   allocation with 808560 free bytes and 789KB until OOM at
>   dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method) at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method) at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:939) at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:912) at
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:879) at
>   android.media.session.MediaSessionLegacyHelper.scaleBitmapIfTooBig(MediaSessionLegacyHelper.java:457)
>   at
>   android.media.session.MediaSessionLegacyHelper.getOldMetadata(MediaSessionLegacyHelper.java:119)
>   at
>   android.media.RemoteController.onNewMediaMetadata(RemoteController.java:1192)
>   at android.media.RemoteController.access$900(RemoteController.java:61)
>   at
>   android.media.RemoteController$MediaControllerCallback.onMetadataChanged(RemoteController.java:821)
>   at
>   android.media.session.MediaController$MessageHandler.handleMessage(MediaController.java:1077)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)

It doesn't mention my package name anywhere, but I do have a Service that implements RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener and has a RemoteController field.

[The full file is available on GitHub](https://github.com/geecko86/QuickLyric/blob/master/QuickLyric/src/main/java/com/geecko/QuickLyric/services/NotificationListenerService.java), if you want to read it.

Any idea what I could do to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: This looks like an issue within the OS itself (the music playing app you are using with your app is giving a much too large Bitmap, so much so it breaks the auto-downscaling). Can you file a bug at [b.android.com](http://b.android.com) and I can forward it onto the Android team to fix?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks, it's a huge relief.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210750&thanks=210750&ts=1463867410